# CSS Preprocessor with MAMP & Sublime Text

Tags: less, sublimetext2, mamp

I have just jumped on the Sublime text wagon and really want to optimise my workflow using LESS. I have looked for a plugin that performs the compiling clientside, in fact I could just add the less.js file to all projects, but I can't find anything to explain how to get it to work.

Also I was thinking that it would be best to install something on the Apache server that comes with MAMP to do it server-side and then I wouldn't have to worry about adding certain files and copy the preprocessed client-side code for the production website.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) (Mac Only), which does what you want SO WELL, plus so much more. I really can't say enough good things about it. I'd recommend checking out the site and the videos to see what it offers.

There is also this ST2 plugin:

https://github.com/BBB/sublime-text-2-plugins

I haven't used it personally because of how well CodeKit works. But it is another option.

Just to clarify, these aren't options that install and run on MAMP, but I think once you check them out you'll see they still provide a solution that doesn't require you to add extra files to your projects.